# How to use SharePoint REST API to send outlook invitation (I know how to send email)?

Tags: sharepoint

Thanks for helping me with this issue.
I am trying to send a calendar invitation through the SharePoint Rest API, but couldn't find any documentation about it.
I am able to use sp.utilities.utility.sendemail to send email, and I have the correct ics file as well, just not sure where to put.
Can someone please provide me with a post example of sending outlook invitation by using SharePoint REST API.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the url for O365 calender api :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations

This may resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for the SharePoint API rather than the outlook API in O365.